# Setting up Rails to use multple Redis instances

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

We have set up multple Redis instances in Herkou to handle different caches and queues, how do you set up Rails to use different instances?

Comment: Why do you need multiple instances? Are you using it as a cache, for different services, something else? Normally you can give whatever service will be using Redis an array of URIs.

Answer (score 2):

You can initiate as many redis clients as you want and use the same at different places.

Say something like this,

```
cache1 = Redis.new(host: 'cache1.redis-server.com', port: 6379)
cache2 = Redis.new(host: 'cache2.redis-server.com', port: 6379)

queues = Redis.new(host: 'queues.redis-server.com', port: 6379)

cache1.set('my_key', 'my_value')
queues.lpush('my_queue', 'my_job')
```

If you are also using Sidekiq and want a separate connection for it, refer the docs [here](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Using-Redis)